# Value of Date Range expressions in JasperSoft

Tags: jasper-reports, date-range

I've got a question regarding the value that I can get using a parameter of DateRage in Jasper when I use it as a filter in a report.

Current date Jan 31 2018, so if in my report I specify this expression in the filter

date_from = MONTH - 6 what is the date that I should get?

'July 31 2017' or 'July 01 2017'

I have tried to print this parameter as a variable in a test report but I always get an Error message.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

new Date(new Date().getTime() - 24*60*60*1000)